# Auto generated MapperImpl class returns an entity instead of null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am writing `patchMutation()` in which I use the map method, but in auto-generated `MapperImpl` class I can see it returns an entity instead of null:

```
PersonEntity mapToPatch(PersonInput input, @MappingTarget PersonEntity patchEntity); 

public PersonEntity mapToPatch(PersonInput input, PersonEntity patchEntity {
        if ( input == null ) {
            return patchEntity;
        }
}
```

I want to return the value as `null`.

Does anybody suggest, how to resolve this?

Comment: Why do you want return `null` here? This method is for updating an existing object, so if you want to return `null` in case of `input==null`, do a simple null check for `PersonInput` before calling this method